# I have a problem with the visual code studio python extension, it's not displaying the quick info

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have installed the latest version of python vscode extension , and when I click on the information icon, doesn't show me the definition of every method.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoX01.png)

and I expect information on every method
[information method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG4ct.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → CodeLens